# error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined

Tags: c, linux, autotools, orientdb

I am trying to `automake` the OrientDb C++ library, but getting some errors.

```
Makefile.am:10: error: Libtool library used but 'LIBTOOL' is undefined
Makefile.am:10:   The usual way to define 'LIBTOOL' is to add 'LT_INIT'
Makefile.am:10:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again.
Makefile.am:10:   If 'LT_INIT' is in 'configure.ac', make sure
Makefile.am:10:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
```

https://github.com/tglman/orientdb-c

https://github.com/tglman/orientdb-c/wiki/Install

I have configure.ac and Makefile.am already defined.

I run the following autotools

- aclocal
- autoheader
- automake:

**libtool (GNU libtool) 2.4.2**

configure.ac

```
# -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([orientdb-c],[0.9])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/o_query_internal.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_AWK
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CPP
AC_PROG_INSTALL
AC_PROG_LN_S
AC_PROG_MAKE_SET

LT_INIT

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([malloc.h memory.h netdb.h netinet/in.h stdlib.h string.h sys/ioctl.h sys/socket.h     sys/time.h unistd.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gethostbyname memset socket strchr strcspn strdup strerror])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Things I already tried:

- autoreconf
- aclocal -I /usr/share/libtool
- aclocal -I .

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this error the fix for me was: `sudo apt-get install libtool`.

Comment: Thanks @Casper you saved my lot of time. For centOs folks it is `yum install libtool`.

Answer (score 258):

A good answer for me was to install libtool:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Comment: `brew install libtool` on a Mac, if you use Homebrew.

Answer (score 115):

Fixed it. I needed to run `libtoolize` in the directory, then re-run:

- aclocal
- autoheader

Comment: In my case, I just need to install libtool. `sudo apt-get install libtool`

Comment: @Aust same, brew install libtool for OS X using homebrew

Comment: I find similar question on SO, and all answers were to "just install libtool". Well, I already had libtool installend, and still got the error. *This* answer is what really helped me.

Comment: `port install libtool` also works if you're using macOS (OS X) and MacPorts.

Answer (score 8):

In my case on macOS I solved it with:

```
brew link libtool
```

Answer (score 2):

For mac it's simple:

```
brew install libtool
```

Answer (score 2):

For mac users who might have had a bad experience with brew, unpredictable download behavior, endless dependencies, time to download, and the large amount of space it consumed, I offer an alternative below. Maybe I was brewing incorrectly, but it couldn't hurt to be aware of yet another way (in addition to MacPorts, port install libtool, or xcode, xcode-select --install ).

```
https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/
```

Download the tar.gz file, then extract it

```
tar -xzf libtool-2.4.tar.gz
```

then

```
configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I am one who does not like brew. Thanks.

Comment: I needed `./configure`

Answer (score 1):

For folks who ended up here and are using `CYGWIN`, install following packages in cygwin and re-run:

- cygwin32-libtool
- libtool
- libtool-debuginfo

Answer (score 1):

For people using Tiny Core Linux, you also need to install `libtool-dev` as it has the *.m4 files needed for `libtoolize`.